# How to find and replace a single value in a dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe (dfdirnoswaps) where one of the columns contains ISINs and another containing one value 'Direction' for all rows. A separate dataframe (dfextended) has only one column  also containing only ISINs, with some (but not necessarily all) ISINs matching the other dataframe. I would like to be able to match common ISINs between the dataframes and once this is established, to change the other column in dfdirnoswaps from 'Direction' to 'Extended' only for cases where the ISINs are in both dataframes.

The way I've tried to do this is as follows:

```
dfdirnoswaps = pd.concat([dfdirnoswaps, dfextended], axis =1)
```

to attach the second dataframe to the first. However this doesn't match the ISINs on the corresponding rows, merrily concatenating them onto the first dataframe as separate rows.

If the above were to work my next step would have been to find and replace as follows:

```
for row in dfdirnoswaps:
    if dfdirnoswaps['ISIN'] == dfdirnoswaps['ISIN2']:
        row in dfdirnoswaps['Strategy'] == 'Extended'
```

('Strategy' is the name of the column that contains 'Direction' for all rows)

I've thought about how I would approach this in excel so it is very likely that there is a much more efficient way to do it than the above, to which I welcome any advice.

Comment: see the wiki for the pandas tag for how to create a reproducible example, which is essential to asking a good question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use the `isin()` method of the dataframe along with masking to make this happen. Let's first create some fake data that looks like yours:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ISIN': [1, 2, 3, 5]})
df1['Strategy'] = 'Direction'
print(df1)
   ISIN   Strategy
0     1  Direction
1     2  Direction
2     3  Direction
3     5  Direction

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ISIN':[3, 4, 5, 6]})
print(df2)
   ISIN
0     3
1     4
2     5
3     6
```

Now we compute a boolean mask using `isin()` and change these results to `'Extended'`:

```
matches = df1['ISIN'].isin(df2['ISIN'])
df1.loc[matches, 'Strategy'] = 'Extended'
print(df1)
   ISIN   Strategy
0     1  Direction
1     2  Direction
2     3   Extended
3     5   Extended
```

(note that the [`isin()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) method checks if each value *is in* another sequence; similarity to your `"ISIN"` column name is purely coincidence).

Comment: Thanks - and for the fake data - the above has worked perfectly. As a follow up, how would I do exactly the same but instead of replacing a string, adding two floating values together?